# What conditions could create an everlasting Radioactive Zone?

Tags: radiation

So, after the apocalypse ravaged the world in WW3, people in the western parts of Russia were in a serious predicament. The radiation in the Western part of Russia (Moscow, Stalingrad, Kaluga) made the place uninhabitable, and the population there were forced to make an exodus to the eastern parts of Russia like Siberia, or went south to places like Kazakhstan or Mongolia.

The two halves of Russia are separated by a zone called the “Velikiy Pylat” or 
"Great Glow", for us English speakers, which goes from Kazan to the Russia Belarus border, and the center of the Zone is Moscow.

The radiation exposure for an unprotected human ranges from 300 rads/second at the edge of the zone to 7000 rads/second at the very center. This Radioactive Zone has to last for at least 750 years without the radiation dissipating too much.  What conditions could cause this Radiation Zone to exist?

Comment: Create an account, this is getting annoying.

Comment: Chernobyl won't be habitable for 20,000 years without intervention. Lasting 750 years is no problem.

Comment: @Vincent: Every Time I leave this website, it logs me out.

Comment: It's because you never registered.

Comment: radiation from a nuke will decline over time. Enough nukes will keep it deadly for 1000 years. You'd need a malfunctioning reactor or black hole to keep radiation constant.   Also: Russia is a big place. Making a whole chunk of country irradiated will require enough nukes to cause nuclear winter on entire planet.   And please find a native Russian speaker; it should not be too hard these days.

Comment: @Samuel what? technically it is habitable now. I mean, you may live there for decades (and some people do, ignoring attempts to depose them) and a lot of animals moved in while humans largely abandoned place. Issue is the presence of toxic metals and alpha-particle sources (in deep soil, in dust pockets, in shrubbery) with related health risks. The consequences of reactor leak are far less lethal than a H-bomb, which would produce gamma radiation and far more toxic environment.

Comment: @Bald Bear A native Russian speaker is here, albeit I prefer type in English. And I don't think will use word "great" or "glow" in particular case. More like "big" or "damn" (and its equivalent) "hole". Great Glow translates to pair of very high-strung words in Russian, sounds epic. "Pylat" is a verb for "being aflame"  (very bad transliteration also). Actually, Hellhole would be fitting: "Адова Дыра" (Adova Dyra)

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding, Talos 4! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. You may also find [meta] and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) 
useful. Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want something so incredibly hot?  Your zone is so deadly that people will keel over before reaching it!  (Even if the source has a discrete edge any local source will spread it, there will be a zone outside it that gets some radiation.)

Furthermore, your energy levels simply don't work.

At the center of your zone you have 7000 rad/sec.  That's .07 joules per gram.  A mass of water subjected to this will be heated by 1 degree C every 14 seconds.  We have a large zone of this, it's ability to shed heat will be very limited.  The only way I can see for heat to be shed adequately is for the material to vaporize and flow away.  You're not going to have the glow of radiation, you're going to have a blue-hot (yes, there are things hotter than white-hot.  White-hot is simply the limit for chemical processes) plume of plasma rising up and spreading around the planet.  This is an extinction level event.

As for how to obtain that:  This is way beyond the radiation level of an operating reactor core.  Nothing can survive at the heat level it produces.  The closest I have even seen suggested is a deep space nuclear engine where you feed weapons-grade material into a reaction chamber that keeps it way supercritical and confines it magnetically.  (The exhaust stream is incredibly dirty, nobody sane would want to use one on a planet.)

Thus the source must be external.  I can see only one source that might even be in the ballpark:  A neutron star or black hole has captured the Earth and your radiation zone is the result of one of the polar jets.  (I can't think of an orbit that keeps it pointed at Russia, though.)  Note that the capture is cataclysmic and the close proximity of the offending body will probably sterilize the planet on it's own.

Comment: I agree, that place sounds  hotter than reactor active zone.. Though, there are natural underground "reactors" that produce close levels to a weak reactor, the described power level is  hundreds times powerful. Water and air around place would also low blue because of Cherenkov radiation. Common rule is that if you see that glow, you're dead. Within time of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Question, what type of radiation it is?

Those conditions hardly can be created by nuclear warfare. By power output levels, it seem that the condition would be equal to a mining world from "Berserker's Base" short stories book. Or Golkonda from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Land_of_Crimson_Clouds .

Presence of radioactive minerals in large quantities enough to create a natural "active zone" is only reason for such level of radiation, that wouldn't only  make atmosphere glow, overheat and escape, but also might melt and burn everything around by sheer heat generated.